# using environment variables with dots in the name in a nomad env block // bunkerweb as an LB in nomad

Tags: nomad

I'm trying to use `bunkerweb` (which is an `nginx` with `modsecurity` included based WAF/reverse proxy) as a load balancer in a `nomad` deployment.

As a docker container, `bunkerweb` relies on env vars to specify the relevant proxy configuration, e.g. `myhost.domain.com_REVERSE_PROXY_URL = "/"` etc., which I consider very good UX generally, but it poses a problem since I can't get `nomad` to accept env var keys with dots in them.

The [docs say](https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/docs/job-specification/env#environment-variables-with-dots) to use "an alternative map assignment syntax", but it is nowhere specified what this looks like.

Searching the webs only gives me convoluted solutions using `template {}` that end up writing an env file somewhere, and no info on how to direct the `nomad` task to actually use this env file when it spawns a `docker` (or in my case `podman`) instance of the container (without overriding entrypoints and mounting said env files and such).

Ideally I really just want to pass said env vars directly to the executed container.

Somewhat related: I've read somewhere I can refer (dynamically) to upstream services with e.g. `http://my-web-app.service.consul:80`, but I saw no conclusive info on where/how to make sure in the task definition that the service `my-web-app` registers itself with consul under its own name. Is this implicit/automagic?